# What does same hat with multiple colour means?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I got two secret hat and both are same just a colour difference. What does it means? Are they related?[image]

Comment: @PeterJ ooops....posted a close vote. I think straight delete will be rude. It can be helpful.

Comment: They differ in more than just the colour of the shirt.

Comment: Missed the detailing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the same "hat".

Those two are *different* "hats".

Go to http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com to find out what they mean.

Comment: Actually, both of those hats are secret hats. You won't find them or what they mean on the winter bash site.